# MailboxProcessor.Dispose does not make object GC collectible

Tags: asynchronous, memory-leaks, f#, idisposable, mailboxprocessor

I am stuck with fixing my TFS tests runs for an F# project that uses MailboxProcessor. The problem is the following warning that I receive from the TFS test runner:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

I guess the problem is caused by the MailboxProcessor. The following snippet demonstrates the problem (I run it from fsi):

```
open System.Threading
open System

type TestDisposable () =
    let cts = new CancellationTokenSource ()
    let processMessage (inbox:MailboxProcessor<int>) =
        let rec loop n =
            async {
                let! msg = inbox.Receive ()
                return! loop (n+msg)
            }
        loop 0

    let agent = MailboxProcessor<int>.Start (processMessage, cts.Token)

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose () =
            (agent :> IDisposable).Dispose ()
            cts.Cancel ()
            cts.Dispose ()
            printfn "TestDisposable.Dispose called"

do
    let weakTarget = 
        use target = new TestDisposable ()
        new WeakReference (target)

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() |> ignore
    GC.Collect()

    printfn "WeakTarget is alive: %b" weakTarget.IsAlive
```

I expect the output line to say that weakTarget is **dead**. But its **alive**.
I think it indicates some memory leak. The question is what do I do wrong?
And the second question is whether the GC problem is related to the TFS test runner problem.

Comment: I would say that the initial error may be caused by the fact that mailboxprocessors may spin up extra threads which stay around after the mailboxprocessor is disposed.  This is an entirely natural performance optimisation.

Comment: Agree. And the question is "how do I kill mailboxprocessor with all its goodness"?

Comment: I ran a simple test of whether the garbage collection actually occurs by running an infinite loop of creating new `TestDisposable`.  After 500k iterations, I saw no increase in memory usage.  I suggest that your `GC` functions are not doing what you think.

Comment: And I again agree. Although, I use this construct in C# successfully (provided the unit test projects built without optimization) to test for memory leaks, that originate from forgotten event handlers, that ought to be unregistered. So, there is some descrepancy between F# and C# here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example code you have posted will keep a reference to `target`, probably because you have a top level binding to it (`use target = new TestDisposable()`).

If you change the code to something like the below code you will see that `weakTarget` is dead because the reference to `target` is only local to the `test()` function.

```
do
    let test() =
        use target = new TestDisposable()
        new WeakReference(target)

    let weakTarget = test()    

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() |> ignore
    GC.Collect()

    printfn "WeakTarget is alive: %b" weakTarget.IsA
```

I don't know if this fixes your original problem though, as this is fairly specfic to the way you have written the example code.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, that helped to solve both problems. I used to create a test target in a let binding in the TestClass' default ctor, that caused the problem with AppDomainUnloadedException. Now I have moved the target initialization to every TestMethods body, and its ok. Although I don't really understand why in my original example the reference to target stays even after the target reached the end of its scope.

Comment: Maybe because shorthand syntax (the full syntax is "let x =... in ...") hides the fact that the rest of the body following the let is a holding the let statement as a closure?